# How to implicitly cast between C++ templates with different template parameters

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a C++ template class wrapping an integer value and checking that this value is always inside a valid range, so the simplified code is the following one:

```
struct OutOfRangeError  
{ };  

template<int MIN, int MAX, typename TYPE>  
struct IntegerRange  
{  
    private:  
    TYPE mValue;  

    public:  
    IntegerRange(const TYPE value) : mValue(value)  
    {  
        if (MIN > value || value > MAX)  
        {  
            throw OutOfRangeError();  
        }  
    }  

    operator TYPE() const  
    {  
        return mValue;  
    }  
}
```

The previous code works but it has a little drawback when using this class. Here is a sample:

```
typedef IntegerRange<0, 4, int> range1_t;  
typedef IntegerRange<0, 5, int> range2_t;  

range1_t a = 3;  
//range2_t b = a; // This does not work  
range2_t b = static_cast<int>(a); // This works OK
```

So, to assign values between different ranges I have to explicitly cast to the TYPE given. I would like to have a solution to avoid having this explicit cast and dealing with IntegerRange class as they were normal integers. So the developer should have the feeling he is dealing with normal integer instead of classes.

To solve this I tried different things. One working is the following one as an additional constructor:

```
template<typename RANGE_TYPE>  
IntegerRange(const RANGE_TYPE &value) :  
        mValue(static_cast<const TYPE>(value))  
{  
    if (MIN > mValue || mValue > MAX)  
    {  
        throw OutOfRangeError();  
    }  
}
```

However, even if this works, I do not like too much as RANGE_TYPE can be any type able to cast to TYPE, and I would like to restrict this to only IntegerRange classes. To restrict it only to IntegerRange classes I tried the following but it is not compiling and I do not understand the reason:

```
template<int ARG_MIN, int ARG_MAX, typename ARG_TYPE>  
IntegerRange(const IntegerRange<ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, typename ARG_TYPE> &value) :  
        mValue(static_cast<const TYPE>(value))  
{  
    if (MIN > value || value > MAX)  
    {  
        throw OutOfRangeError();  
    }  
}
```

The questions are 2:
* Why the last piece of code is not compiling and what I need to change to compile it.
* Is there any better to avoid the explicit cast I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The error message is: error: conversion from ‘range1_t {aka IntegerRange<0, 4, int>}’ to non-scalar type ‘range2_t {aka IntegerRange<0, 5, int>}’ requested on gcc.

Comment: Can you post your whole code verbatim? I think it should work.

Comment: I am getting the following error on g++ ../lib/src/IntegerRanges.hpp:141:31: error: expected '>' before numeric constant
../lib/src/IntegerRanges.hpp:142:84: error: template argument 3 is invalid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305952/overloading-assignment-operator-in-a-class-template-that-can-cast-to-another-tem

Comment: Try deleting "typename" from the second line of last code snippet.

Comment: In case of interest, I just updated the whole code in github but without the last snippet, as it is not compiling. Note in the whole code this class is called StaticIntegerRange instead of IntegerRange. https://github.com/carlos-sancho-ramirez/cpp-integer-ranges

Comment: I'm a little sceptical as to whether the bounds should be part of the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **you shouldn't use `ARG_MAX` as a template name** since it may already be defined as a *POSIX* numeric constant.

Secondly, you should remove the `typename` in the third template argument of `IntegerRange` :

```
IntegerRange(const IntegerRange<ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_TYPE> &value) :
```

Also maybe you should cast `value` to `ARG_TYPE` which will directly call your `operator ARG_TYPE()`  and then let the compiler convert from `ARG_TYPE` to `TYPE` instead of casting to `TYPE` and let the compiler infer the possible conversion from  `ARG_TYPE` and the call to `operator ARG_TYPE()`. With the first solution, the compilation errors regarding impossible conversions may be more explicit.

Comment: You might be right about the ARG_TYPE casting instead of TYPE. But I regret to say it is still not compiling and more errors are appearing. ../lib/src/IntegerRanges.hpp:153:31: error: expected '>' before numeric constant
../lib/src/IntegerRanges.hpp:154:67: error: 'ARG_TYPE' was not declared in this scope
../lib/src/IntegerRanges.hpp:154:75: error: template argument 3 is invalid

Comment: What compiler are you using ? It compiles fine under GCC 4.7.

Comment: @Charlie I get the same error on Linux, since `ARG_MAX` is a numeric constant, just rename your template parameters.

Comment: You solved the problem, I removed typename and changed the ARG_TYPE name to another and now it is working perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> RANGE_TYPE can be any type able to cast to TYPE, and I would like to
>   restrict this to only IntegerRange classes. To restrict it only to
>   IntegerRange

Just interchange the order of the template arguments and declare as

```
template<typename TYPE, TYPE2 MIN, TYPE2 MAX>  
struct IntegerRange
```

This will work because template argument deduction doesn't implicitly convert arg types. for example float to int.

---

---

```
//range2_t b = a; // This does not work
```

Of course. `a` and `b` have different types. Remember for each template specialization a new template of the class is created. You can't assign two objects because their types look similar.

```
class A { int a; }; class B { int a; };
A a; B b; a = b;  // Should not work
```

In order to do `a = b` you need to provide copy constructor that can construct an `IntegerRange` from another `IntegerRange`. (You don't need assignment here because you have the type conversion operator.)

```
template<typename TYPE2, TYPE MIN2, TYPE MAX2>
IntegerRange(const IntegerRange<TYPE2,MIN2,MAX2>& ot) {
    if (MIN > ot.mValue || ot.mValue > MAX)  
    {  
        throw OutOfRangeError();  
    }  

    mValue = ot.mValue;
}
```

Comment: Actually, by doing `range2_t b = a;`, I think he was expecting the compiler to call the `operator int()` of  `a` and the constructor `IntegerRange(const int)` of `b`. But of course, a C++ compiler is not designed to infer that far.