# c++ left hand assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

i have a class (wich should hold any value) like this:

```
class Value
{

    public:

        Value();
        Value(const Value& value);
        virtual ~Value();
        void operator= (const Value& value);

        template<class T>
        void operator= (T value);
...
}
```

now my question:

why can't i implement an assignment operator for this class like this:

```
template<class T>
void operator=(T& value, const Value& v)
{...}
```

I wan to desing a class wich works the following:

```
Value v;

v = 'c';
v = 13;
v = 5.6;
int i = 5;
v = &i;

int y = v;
char b = v;
```

i want to put any datatype into it and out of it.
at the moment this works fine for:

```
v = 'c';
v = 13;
v = 5.6;
```

but not for:

```
int y = v;
```

what works is:

```
int y = v.get<int>();
```

but this is not as nice as

```
int y = v;
```

would be

Comment: Is that a typo in your question? Did you mean `void operator=`?

Comment: See [Overloading assignment operator in a class template that can cast to another template type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305952/overloading-assignment-operator-in-a-class-template-that-can-cast-to-another-tem).

Comment: Why would you want to implement it like this? What problem do you believe it would help you solve?

Comment: Just call the function `assign` instead of `operator=` and all will be good. If not, then you have a much more serious design problem anyway.

Comment: yes sorry it is a typo. i will correct it

Comment: BTW , it's expected that `operator=` will return a reference to `*this`, so its signature should be `Value& operator=(T)`.

Comment: Look into Boost::Any or Boost::Variant unless you're just doing this for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily fix the compilation error by adding template type cast to your class like following:

```
class Value
{
...
        template <class T> operator T();
};

Value va;
int i = va;
```

I still believe you will find the task of implementing 'boost::any' yourself quite challenging, but why not? :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the standard says that an assignment operator must be a member function with only one parameter.

13.5.3$1 Assignment [over.ass]:

> An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function with exactly one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a typecast operator like this

```
operator int()
{
    if(current_value_is_not_int)
        throw MyException("Current value is not int");

    //return int value
}
```