# overload assignment operator for template class

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator

I am trying to overload `operator=()`, but I am getting `error: no viable overloaded '='`. But I don't understand why. What am I missing here? I tired following the answers in [Overloading assignment operator in a class template that can cast to another template type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305952/overloading-assignment-operator-in-a-class-template-that-can-cast-to-another-tem) but there people say to give the template arguments of the return type a new type... ? That leads to the compiler complaining about an unknown type for me.

```
template<typename T, typename P>
class SomeClass
{

public:

    SomeClass<T, P> operator=(SomeClass<T, P>& src)
    {
        if (this != &src)
        {
            vectorfield.resize(src.vectorfield.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < src.vectorfield.size(); ++i)
            {
                vectorfield[i] = src.vectorfield[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vectorfield;
};



template<typename SC>
class SomeOtherClass
{

public:

    typedef SC someclass_type;

    void func()
    {
       sc = someclass_type();
    }

private:
    someclass_type sc;
};


int main()
{

    typedef SomeClass<int, int> SCII;
    typedef SomeOtherClass<SCII> SOC_scii;

    SOC_scii soc_scii;
    soc_scii.func();


}
```

Comment: FWIW, You don't need to use `SomeClass<T, P>` inside the class template. You can use just `SomeClass`.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `<T, P>` in the operator definition aren't necessary. And you don't actually need to implement an assignment operator.

Comment: BTW, implementation can simply be `{ vectorfield = src.vectorfield; return *this; }` or even `SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& rhs) = default;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with temporaries, like in

```
   sc = someclass_type();
```

the parameter to the assignment operator should be a `const` reference.

```
SomeClass<T, P>& operator=(const SomeClass<T, P>& src)
               ^           ^^^^^
```

The assignment operator also generally returns are reference to the assigned object (so it can be used in chained assignments like `a = b = c;`). Returning by value would create an additional copy, which we probably don't want.

Comment: And return a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your assignment operator's signature to:

```
SomeClass<T, P>& operator=(SomeClass<T, P> const &src)
               ^                           ^^^^^
```

You have to return by reference to allow assignment chaining as show below:

```
SomeClass<T, P> a, b, c;
a = b = c;
```

The input parameter must be of of `const` reference otherwise you won't be able to assign temporary objects.

Comment: Returning a reference might help.